# series solution confusion first order differntial

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Hi I am having an issue with this series solution I just cant seem to figure out where I am going wrong. My book gives the ans $y=a_{1}x$ as the solution but I just cant seem to se why.

Here is the question and working so far.

$$xy'=y$$

$$y=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^n$$
$$y'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(a_n)x^{n-1}$$

So putting these back in to the series I get

$$x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(a_n)x^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^n$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(a_n)x^{n}=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}x^n$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(a_n)x^{n}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}x^n=a_{0}$$

$$\sum_{1}^{\infty}a_n(n-1)x^n=a_0$$

And this is my confusion lies because $a_1=0$ as with everything else when I expand the series to compare the coefficients.

Comment: the serie derviated should start at n=1  $y'=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(a_n)x^{n-1}$

Comment: sorry that is a typo i will edit

Comment: it changes a lot in your calculation because you start at n=0

Comment: yeah but I am still getting confused

Comment: Jason do the calculations properly again...it's going to be clear

Comment: you'll get coefficients $a_n(n-1)$ they all should be 0 except $a_1$ because when $n=1$, $n-1=0$

Comment: ah! clocked it. normally I expand the series and compare the cofficent without acually thinking about the nth term  of the series. i.e when n=n. So now I see that $$a_n(n-1)=0$$ now it clear. Thank you guys

Comment: why using series for this question? wont it be a lot easier to just say $x\dfrac{dy}{dx}=y$ and integrate when you get $\ln y=\ln x +c_1\implies y=xe^{c_1}=xc_2$?

Comment: yes but, it is a book question and my lectures are currently on series solutions it is practice for legendre equations ect